# Meaning of the following passage with the word "shed" in it

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> From phobias to panic attacks, anxiety disorders can cause major disruption to sufferers' lives. Could smartphones and tablets offer a solution? Spiders used to terrify psychiatrist Russell Green. He recalls one incident, involving a colleague, which led him to flee his workplace. "Her son had tarantulas and **she'd brought in the skin that one had shed**," Dr Green explains. "I just happened to be passing through the entrance to the hospital and she had it in a sandwich box. "I immediately saw it and recognised it as a tarantula and tried to run out of the hospital." Dr Green's arachnophobia - the exaggerated fear of spiders - is so severe that even a picture of one is enough to scare him.

I know the word **shed** has to do with **getting rid of sonething,** but it is still difficult to figure out what the above phrase really means: Bring in? Bring in the skin? Had shed? I am confused. I have completly drawn a blank here!

Answer (score 5):

To shed is indeed "to get rid of", in the sense of "shaking it off your back". A cat sheds fur, and as we learn in this article, spiders shed their skin. It means that they lose a layer of old skin, that will then be lying around.

That skin was picked up by the mentioned colleague, and it was *brought in* to the workplace.

> she'd brought in the skin that one had shed
>
> She had brought with her into the office the empty skin that one of her son's tarantulas had crawled out of.

Comment: 'lying' not 'laying'

Answer (score 2):

In this case, her son's pet tarantula molted (shed it's exoskeleton).

She picked up the spiders old 'skin' and took to her workplace where Dr. Green also works.

So, yes, she literally carried spider skin to the office.